# On Windows 2000, "The procedure entry point EncodePointer could not be located in the dynamic link library KERNEL32.dll"

Tags: windows, windows-2000

I have IObit's **Advanced SystemCare8.2 Pro** installed on my old computer running **Windows 2000**. When I run ASC8 or any of its associated functions I get the following message when I open the program.

> The procedure entry point EncodePointer could not be located in the
>   dynamic link library KERNEL32.dll.

Clicking "OK" will close the message and allow me to run ASC8 but that does not work for me to run any of the associated functions like **Monitor.exe**.  Is there anyway to work around this in Win2k or do I need a newer operating system to fix this problem?

My hardware would support Windows XP if I could get a copy with all the service packs.  The problem being that WinXP is no longer supported just like Win2K so I've no idea what new problems will arise if I try to upgrade to XP.

Comment: Does this software even support windows 2000?

Comment: The software clearly states "Supports Windows XP/Vista/7/8/8.1" under the "download" button at http://www.iobit.com/en/advancedsystemcarefree.php . Windows 2000 is not in that list.

Answer (score 4):

The Win32 kernel API function [EncodePointer](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb432254%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) was added in Windows XP SP2 (client) and Windows Server 2003 SP1 (server). *These are the absolute minimum versions of Windows that provide the requested functionality.*

Hence, if the software you are trying to run needs it (which it sounds like; there would be no reason to map it otherwise), that software **is not and can never be compatible with Windows 2000.**

You *may* be able to get this software to run by upgrading to Windows XP SP2, *assuming* (which is quite a big assumption) that this is the only additional thing needed. The correct thing to do would be to contact the software vendor and determine what minimum version of Windows is supported by the software in question, then use at least that.